# On Gitlab, how to view a file as of commit ref

Tags: git, gitlab

On Gitlab, how to view a file as of commit ref? I know that that on command line git, the command is:

```
git show <commit ref>:<file_name>
```

how to I do the same on gitlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to URL https://gitlab.com/$USER/$REPO/blob/$SHA1/path/to/file

For example, https://gitlab.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/2ce592300bdd0cfcb444b24cdfd4b2e412fd7bda/sqlobject/main.py — this is `/sqlobject/main.py` file from commit `2ce5923` of [SQLObject](http://sqlobject.org/). `User` is `sqlobject`, repository is also `sqlobject`.

Comment: thanks. here is a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069291/on-gitlab-how-to-compare-a-file-of-two-different-commits