# On GitLab, how to compare a file of two different commits

Tags: git, gitlab

On GitLab, how to compare a file of two different commits? I know that that on command line git, the command is:

```
git diff commit1 commit12 -- file_name
```

What is the link format to do this on GitLab?

See my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525235/on-gitlab-how-to-view-a-file-as-of-commit-ref)

Comment: I see a way to compare commits at Gitlab but I doubt you can select a file in the comparison — you have to navigate to the file in the entire list of changed files.

Comment: @phd yes, I show the option to compare complete revision, but then again, when you click one of the file names it scrolls down to the correct place, which is good enough for me, The problem is, to specify the correct place, you need to add a hash parameter, which seems arbitrary. is there a way to calculate it?

Comment: No idea. You have to find the algorithm in gitlab sources.

Comment: It's just [the SHA-1 hash of the file path](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v12.1.0/lib/gitlab/diff/position.rb#L138).

Comment: @yigal this still has no accepted answer, but I think you have found one, didn't you?

Comment: @SimonSobisch last time I was working on this it looked to me that GitLab actually cant do that. that might have changed since then, but I am no longer with the project

Comment: There is an entry in the issue tracker for GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28555).

Answer (score 156):

It will compare commits, you will be able to find file in list.

1. go to Repository > Compare
2. paste this url: https://gitlab.com/$USER/$REPO/compare?from=$SHA1&to=$SHA2 or https://*your gitlab domain*/$ORG/$GROUP/$REPO/-/compare?from=$SHA1&to=$SHA2
3. hit enter (notice: gitlab will set 'Source' and 'Target' properly)
4. click button 'compare'

Comment: thanks, but this will compare entire commits. I need a link to compare a single file between two commits

Comment: Go and search for your file in the listing, you can expand and see the changes

Comment: Tried that, but its not working, I get: `There isn't anything to compare. You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison.`

Comment: @Adam For me it works when you use full commit SHAs, like:
https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>/compare/0fd28f337bd110f2fe0f8bb03bd7c95f4007cf90...4e08585433450194b073eca5f3dce57cf98124de

Comment: @adam try reversing the order.  Put the newer commit first, the older commit second.  (its a known issue)

Comment: That's a sweet hack, thanks. It worked for me only with @TomaszRozmus enhancement.
It saved me from a disconnection between local and remote, where I could make sure that remote had literally no difference from local but it was preventing push. Then pulled and pushed and everything went back to working fine.

Comment: @johnktejik thank you so much, I could never make sense of the error message Gitlab gave me when putting the older commit first.

Comment: @johnktejik thank you so much for the reverse order solution. Works fine and I would never have thought to try it because it seems very much counter-intuitive, especially when it says there is no difference rather than showing the diffs the other way around, strange

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with GitLab `15.2.4-ee`.

Comment: @yigal "I need a link to compare a single file between two commits" This is so easy to do in Bitbucket, why does Gitlab make it so hard?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. With the complete SHA of the older commit first I get the error "There isn't anything to compare. You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison."; with the newer commit first it shows that there are zero changes when in fact there are some.

Comment: Unreal tips!! Thanks a lot. Saved a lot of my time.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of being unable to find the file in the list. Sometimes commits involve a large number of files, and gitlab does not support searching filenames to narrow the field. How can one find a specific file in a commit comparison?

Answer (score 29):

It appears the direct URL for compare is as follows

```
# compare URL, where ref_source and ref_target can be commit SHA, tag, or branch
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/${ref_target}...${ref_source}

# tag example 1, comparing tag v1.5.1 to master
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/v1.5.1...master

# tag example 2, comparing tag v1.5.1 to tag v1.5.2
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/v1.5.1...v1.5.2

# commit example 1, comparing commit SHA to master
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/f6098082f...master

# commit example 2, comparing commit SHA to another commit SHA
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/f6098082f...2b8daf28
```

To compare a single file across two commits, one needs to get a blob id of the file first, and append it to the compare url following a octothorp (`#`); gotta find a way to get that id though

```
# compare URL, where ref_source and ref_target can be commit SHA, tag, or branch, and file_blob
https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/${ref_target}...${ref_source}#${file_blob}
```

And the compare UI can be reached at `https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare`, where you can select source and target refs via drop-down.

Comment: When I try to compare two commints I get `
There isn't anything to compare. You'll need to use different branch names to get a valid comparison.`

Comment: For comparing two commits a typical URL is `https://gitlab.com/myusername/myproject/-/compare/6e58206f...f6312dbc`. I pootled around, and eventually Gitlab rewrote my attempt thus (with that extra hyphen). I'm a bit disappointed that the excellent Gitlab makes it so hard to `git diff` between two random commits.

Comment: When I enter two commits, GitLab compares all the files, including commits between the two, i.e., for all the commits between the common ancestor of the two targets.

I want to strictly compare the files that are touched by the two commits. Is this a limitation of GitLab?

Answer (score 16):

None of the other answers had the correct steps to show a diff between two branches via the Gitlab GUI in its current version.  To do so:

1. Go to your project
2. Hover over "Repository" in the side-menu and click "Branches"
3. Next to the branch you wish to compare, click the "Compare" button on the right.
4. You can then change the target branch from `master` (or whatever your default branch is called) if you wish.
5. At the top is commits.  Scroll down to see the actual diffs for each modified file.
6. Scroll to the specific file you want to compare and click to expand if necessary.

Comment: After step 4 just update URL with your Commit ids

Comment: @ADV-IT I was able to "hack this way" on GitHub, but not on GitLab, though...somebody knows why?

Comment: 6. And what if there are thousands of files? GitLab only lets you search for the 20 files for some stupid reason. Unless you know exactly on what page of the diff your file will end up, it's unusable.

Answer (score 7):

You can open two tabs:

1. go the list of commits (in the sidebar: `Repository -> Commits`), from where you have the `SHA` of any given commit (there's the copy button on right) handy;
2. go the the compare tool (in the sidebar: `Repository -> Compare`), and at the top, in `source` and `target`, past the `SHA` strings of the two commits you want to compare.

Answer (score 5):

You first need to get the [sha1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) digest of the file path you are interested in (for instance with the [sha1sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum) command). You can then build the URL to display the diff between two [git ref](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) (i.e. branch names or commit hash or tags) as follows:

```
https://gitlab.com/<project>/-/compare/<ref1>...<ref2>#<sha1>
```

Here is an example with the **AN/R5/L15/S2018/IDS/000/020/RUANR5L15S2018IDS20864.json** filename. Its sha1 is **f88a5e03ecc7854e8955927af33f2ea9d090ddaf**:

```
$ echo -n AN/R5/L15/S2018/IDS/000/020/RUANR5L15S2018IDS20864.json | sha1sum
f88a5e03ecc7854e8955927af33f2ea9d090ddaf
```

Comparing it between the **878bd4f4f7edbabad3c691a7df3e317348d4ca77** and **59e63f529a7fe5f28131dec36f253dca46b8ba9c** commits is done with the URL: https://git.en-root.org/tricoteuses/data.tricoteuses.fr/Agenda_XV/-/compare/59e63f529a7fe5f28131dec36f253dca46b8ba9c...878bd4f4f7edbabad3c691a7df3e317348d4ca77#f88a5e03ecc7854e8955927af33f2ea9d090ddaf

The page will also display other diffs, not just the one you are interested in. But it will move you right where the diff of the file starts and you can ignore the rest.

There are [a few GitLab feature requests](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22245) to make it easier for the user to discover this in the future.

Comment: This fails if the diff of said JSON file is not on page 1, since it's a HTML anchor the browser scrolls to.

Answer (score 1):

As addition to the answer from @anapsix  by using this url:

`https://${gitlab_host}/${repo_path}/-/compare/${ref_target}...${ref_source}`

That solution still works, but `${ref_target}` and `${ref_source}` are not the commit SHA key. You will need the short version of that key: only the first  8-chracters.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the menu:

[image]

There is a tool to compare side-by-side

Comment: What menu, how does one find it? How does this help with the issue of comparing a single file vs an entire commit on potentially thousands of files?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to compare one file different version

1.Repositoy->Commits->select file->click Side-by-side

2.you will see two windows,left is old version and right is new version.

Comment: This will show changes from a single commit only relative to its parent.

Answer (score -2):

You can accomplish this with simple point-and-click through the GitLab web interface, provided the code can be viewed on the screen.

- On your repository, click on the left Menu option "Commits". The right pane will show a list of all the commit events in the repository.
- Click on the one that corresponds to the file you're interested in. You will be able to see its "before and after" state.
- You can see it in "inline" or "side-by-side" mode, where it highlights changes in green.