# Show all changes made between a range of commits in GitLab UI

Tags: gitlab

Say I have 10 commits in my merge request. I'd like to see all changes made between the first commit and the second to last commit. How can I see this in the GitLab UI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Gitlab, how to compare a file of two different commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069291/on-gitlab-how-to-compare-a-file-of-two-different-commits)

Answer (score 4):

1. You can view 'Changes' tab to view all changes in merge request
2. You can also click on individual commits to view what is changed in that particular commit
3. You can check diff between two arbitrary commits using https://gitlab.com/$USER/$REPO/compare?from=$SHA1&to=$SHA2

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070145/2073920

Answer (score 4):

Use format

```
https://gitlab.com/$USER/$REPOSITORY/compare?from=commit_hashtag1&to=commit_hashtag2
```

For example, You use URL like this

https://gitlab.com/Donhu/java_examples/compare?from=7f844e6b&to=1ff5c89c

[image]

[image]